# What are the syntax options for displaying the date and time on the Linux taskbar?

Tags: linux-mint

Example:

If I do

```
%a %B %y %m %M %S
```

It will display

```
Thu March 16 03 52 33
```

It displays the time in 24 hour format. I want the 12 hour format instead.

Are there any options I can do to make it display this?

```
Thu 3/16 1:53PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends on which taskbar you're using. There's *dozens* of them.

However, your example seems to be using the [strftime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/strftime.3.html) syntax, in which...

- abbreviated weekday (Thu) is `%a`,
- month number (03) is `%m`,
- month number without leading zeros (3) is `%-m`,
- day number (18) is `%d`,
- hours (12-hour) are `%I`,
- the same without leading zeros are `%-d` or `%-I`,
- minutes are `%m`,
- the "AM/PM" sign is `%p`.

---

Note that `%-x` is specific to Linux (glibc), it won't work on other operating systems (even though e.g. BSDs also use strftime).

Also, while in your case this is probably already configured right, for completeness I'll mention that that `%p` seems to only work if the *system locale* is set to one that uses a 12-hour clock. (You don't have to change the main `LANG` setting, just `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` is enough. For example, I want the opposite, so I set `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` to get a 24-hour clock while keeping the rest as `en_US.UTF-8`.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be entirely certain it's the same, but these look like `strftime` variables. Try the following:

```
%a %m/%y %k:%M%P
```

or this which may remove the month padding: (Thanks @grawity)

```
%a %-m/%y %k:%M%P
```

Further information: [strftime glibc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) - [strftime unix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html)

Comment: In Linux glibc, there are several extensions including `%-m` for no padding. See the [glibc strftime manpage.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/strftime.3.html) You'll probably want the same for days and hours.